# nhibernate table per subclass "invalid cast" exception

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Faced some strange problem with table-per-subclass pattern. I've created some object(Bid, see below) and add it to DB using ISession method SaveOrUpdate(obj). It works fine and my tables updated correctly. But when I want to get this object by calling method Get(type,key) I receive error "InvalidCastException: System.String".
After hour of decompiling I've received more information about the error: "Invalid cast exception: couldn't cast System.String to DocumentHolder". I'm really confused about that 'cause I do not see any possible cast from String to DocumentHolder in my code.
You can see code below. (I've deleted all unnecessary items from classes)

```
public abstract class DocumentHolder
{
    public DocumentHolder(){}
    public DocumentHolder(string Id)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    //each subentity has it own Type
    public abstract string EntityType { get; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        var t = obj as DocumentHolder;
        if (t == null)
            return false;
        if (Id == t.Id && EntityType == t.EntityType)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Id + "|" + EntityType).GetHashCode();
    }
}
//Map implementation (simple composite id)
class DocumentHolderMap:ClassMap<DocumentHolder>
{
    public DocumentHolderMap()
    {
        this.CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Id, x => x.Length(50))
            .KeyProperty(x => x.EntityType, x => x.Access.ReadOnly()
                .ColumnName("entity_type"));
    }
}
```

Also I have a child impl:

```
public class Bid : DocumentHolder
{
  public override string EntityType
    {
        get { return "bid"; }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        var t = obj as Bid;
        if (t == null)
            return false;
        if (Id == t.Id && EntityType == t.EntityType)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Id + "|" + EntityType).GetHashCode();
    }
}
class BidMap : SubclassMap<Bid>
{
   public BidMap()
   {
       KeyColumn("id");
       KeyColumn("entity_type");
   }
}
```

Somewhere in the code:

```
//creating a Bid bid;
session.SaveOrUpdate(bid); //works fine
var newBid = session.Get(typeof(Bid),bid.Id); //throws InvalidCastException
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, my mistake.
As I have a class with composite key, I need to Get() it by composite id. Not just string Id. Working code:

```
session.Get(new Bid(Id = "balbal")); //there is the key field "EntityName" generated by default (as it readonly)
```

But exception message was really not informative.